# RadioButton checked field is not working for [No] by default .I had implemented it to set default as No and disable it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

RadioButton checked field is not working for [No] by default .I had implemented it to set default as No and disable it and for Yes to update the fields

By default its coming unchecked for the both fields if i refresh the page.
I need to make it default for "NO"

Tried to fix the issue in various methods and ways but it's not fixing. I am not able to know why it's getting an error I don't understand the exact issue in the code. Could anyone help with the solution?

[image: By default its coming unchecked for the both fields]

if i click Yes the user fields should be editable

[image]

code:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Link,
  FormLabel,
  RadioGroup,
  Radio,
  FormControlLabel,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { TextField, CurrencyTxtField } from "components/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  dinline: {
    display: "inline",
  },
  fieldproductTester: {
    fontWeight: 700,
  },
}));

const ProductTester = ({
  errors,
  values,
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  refProp,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div ref={refProp}>
      <FormLabel color="secondary" component="legend" mb={2}>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h4">
          Testers
        </Typography>
      </FormLabel>
      <Box pt={2}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography component="div" color="textPrimary">
              Would you like to give your customers the option to purchase a
              tester of this product?if so,please include information about the
              tester in the product description.
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={8}>
            <RadioGroup
              className={classes.dinline}
              aria-label="tester"
              name="tester"
              value={values.tester}
              onChange={handleChange}
              disabled={!values.tester}
            >
              <FormControlLabel value="Yes" control={<Radio />} label="Yes"/>
              <FormControlLabel
                value="No"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="No"
                enabled={values.tester === "No"}
              />
            </RadioGroup>
          </Grid>
          {values.tester && (
            <>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography
                  variant="inherit"
                  className={classes.fieldproductTester}
                >
                  Tester Price
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={8}>
                <CurrencyTxtField
                  id="testerPrice"
                  name="testerPrice"
                  label=" "
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={values.testerPrice}
                  currencySymbol="$"
                  outputFormat="number"
                  digitGroupSeparator=""
                  textAlign="left"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  error={!!errors.testerPrice}
                  helperText={errors.testerPrice ? errors.testerPrice : ""}
                  disabled={values.tester === "No"}
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography
                  variant="inherit"
                  className={classes.fieldproductTester}
                >
                  Tester SKU
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={8}>
                <TextField
                  id="productSku"
                  name="sku"
                  label=""
                  ariaLabel="SKU"
                  value={values.sku}
                  disabled={values.tester === "No"}
                />
              </Grid>
            </>
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductTester;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following configuration - it works as expected. "No" is selected as a default value. Try to use this code as a reference point and then add all additional functionality step by step to see when it stops working.

```
<RadioGroup
 aria-label="tester"
 name="tester"
 defaultValue="No">
     <FormControlLabel 
         value="Yes" 
         control={<Radio />} 
         label="Yes"/>
     <FormControlLabel
         value="No"
         control={<Radio />}
         label="No"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Hi the default is "no" and its hides and if i select Yes its display/show and if i click again on  "No" radioButton its only disabled but it was not hiding .              How can i hide if i select "No" after selecting Yes i need to implement transition.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Here is what I see. You want to show an additional text field if "Yes" option is selected and hide the additional field/s whenever it's "No". Am I right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131925/cropping-functionalityreact-easy-crop-is-not-working-when-i-try-to-upload-an-i